# Как написать счетчик для страниц JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Как написать функцию которая будет считать посещение страниц?

В **HTML** документе есть три страницы и мне нужно написать в одной функции счетчик к каждой странице отдельно.

Как это сделать, через ивентлистнер?

Чтоб по итогу выдавало :

`Вы посетили Page1 N раз`

`Вы посетили Page2 N раз`

`Вы посетили Page3 N раз`

То есть написать счетчик в функции `visitLink` к каждой странице, а результат в `viewResults`.

```js
function visitLink(path) {

}


function viewResults() {

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="mx-auto" id="content">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mt-3 mb-5 ml-5">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page1')" href="page_1.html">Page 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page2')" href="page_2.html">Page 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('Page3')" href="page_3.html">Page 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <h3 class="mb-5">Welcome to Local Storage Homework</h3>
    <button type="button" onclick="viewResults()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5">View page visits results</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в localStorage сохраняйте страницу + кол-во посещений

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="mx-auto" id="content">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills mt-3 mb-5 ml-5">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('0')" href="page_1.html" >Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('1')" href="page_2.html">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" onclick="visitLink('2')"href="page_3.html">Page 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h3 class="mb-5">Welcome to Local Storage Homework</h3>
      <button type="button" onclick="viewResults()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mb-5">View page visits results</button>
    </div>
  </div>




function visitLink(path) {
    var info = localStorage.getItem(path+"p");
    localStorage.setItem(path+"p", Number(info)+1)
}


function viewResults() {
    var view = document.getElementsByClassName("mb-5")[1];
    view.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i =0;i<3;i++){
        view.innerHTML = view.innerHTML + "page"+i+" "+Number(localStorage.getItem(i+'p'))+"<br>";
    }
}
```